# Comparação de duas matrizes com tamanhos diferentes

Tags: r, matriz

Tenho duas matrizes com essas dimensões e gostaria de remover as linhas comuns entre as duas matrizes e formar outra matriz sem estes elementos. Como o R poderia fazer isso?

```
a = matrix(1:30, ncol = 5, byrow = T)

b = matrix(6:15, ncol = 5, byrow = T)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alguns jeitos de ser fazer isso (ainda acho que exista algum mais inteligente):

```
a[!apply(a, 1, function(arow) any(apply(b, 1, function(brow) all(brow==arow)))),]
```

Nesse caso, cada linha da matriz `a` vai ser comparada com cada linha da matriz `b`, e se houver alguma linha de `a` com todos elementos iguais a uma linha de `b`, a linha é excluída.

Outra forma é juntar as duas matrizes e utilizar `duplicated()`:

```
ab <- rbind(a, b)
ab[!(duplicated(ab, fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(ab)),]
```

Nesse caso as linhas de `ab` duplicadas são removidas, restando apenas as linhas únicas. É necessário usar `duplicated` duas vezes pois a função só retorna `TRUE` para a segunda ocorrência da linha, por isso procuramos uma vez de cima pra baixo e uma de baixo pra cima, removendo todas linhas duplicadas.

Os dois métodos retornam:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]   16   17   18   19   20
[3,]   21   22   23   24   25
[4,]   26   27   28   29   30
```